# Is there a way to reach a local variable in a child function from the parent function?

Tags: bash, variables, scope, variable-assignment

As part of bash learning, I'am trying with no success to catch a local variable in a child function from the parent function.

```
child_function (){
  declare -a child_arr="${1}"
}

parent_function (){
  child_function "${ARR[@]}"
  echo ${#child_arr[@]}
  echo ${child_arr[*]}
}


ARR=("Cat" "Dog" "Dragon")

parent_function   # prints out 0 and nothing
```

Is there a way to get that local var without not removing the local scope of the var in the child function ?

Comment: If you could do that then there wouldn't be any point in defining local variables

Comment: No. The whole point of local variables is to hide them from outside observers.

Comment: Also, `child_arr` isn't set to the entire array. You passed the elements of `ARR` as separate elements, which means you executed the equivalent of `declare -a child_arr=Cat`.

Comment: @VenomCA: See `help declare | grep local`

Comment: @chepner I tryied to set it entirely with using indirect expansion ``` child_arr="${!1}" ``` but with no more success

Comment: See my answer; `declare -a child_arr=("$@")`. Arrays are not first-class values, so you can't simply assign one array to another.

Comment: @chepner Iam on it. Will back to you eventually

Comment: In ANY programming language, not just bash, if you're trying to access the value of a variable declared in a child function from the parent function then you're trying to break encapsulation and tightly couple 2 different layers of functionality which means you have bad software. If you think you need to do that then think again about your program structure as there is something wrong with it.

Comment: (The definition of "outside observer" gets a little funny in dynamically scoped languages.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, since the defining feature of a local variable is that it is invisible from outside the scope where it is defined.

However, because `bash` is *dynamically* scoped, any function called from within `child_function` has access to the local variables of `child_function`. This suggests that instead of `parent_function` accessing the array, it can specify a function for `child_function` to call. For example,

```
ARR=("Cat" "Dog" "Dragon")

# child_arr will come from a scope higher in the call stack
print_child_arr () {
    echo ${#child_arr[@]}
    echo ${child_arr[*]}
}

child_function (){
    callback=$1
    shift
    declare -a child_arr=("${@}")
    "$callback"

}

parent_function (){
    child_function print_child_arr "${ARR[@]}"
}

parent_function
```

`child_function` and `parent_function` can be simplified slightly by using a nameref:

```
child_function (){
    callback=$1
    declare -n child_arr=$2
    "$callback"

}

parent_function (){
    child_function print_child_arr ARR
}
```